# Inserting image in pdf android

Tags: android, pdf-generation, android-droidtext

How to add image in a pdf using `DroidText` I have tried the following code -

```
Document document = new Document();
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SimpleImages.pdf");
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(f));
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Simple Image"));

Image image =Image.getInstance("file:///mnt/sdcard/img.png");
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

Comment: which error do you get?, Please post your logcat also

Comment: pdf is generated with empty content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved...

```
Image image =Image.getInstance("sdcard/img.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do It Like this.It is working

Image image = Image.getInstance ("file:///mnt/sdcard/Wallpapers/i_love_you.jpg"); 
 document.add(image);